# Django CustomUser redefine password field

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suddenly I had the need to use one of my existing models for authentication. I know that there are several approaches how I can do that, but here I'm wondering is it possible to redefine password field with a way I choosed?

To be more specific: I want django to know that my access_key field is a User password field.

But current code presupposes that I gonna add another field password to Company model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
from django.db import models

from django_extensions.db.fields.encrypted import EncryptedCharField


class CompanyManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, name, email, access_key=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Company must have an email address')

        company = self.model(
            email=CompanyManager.normalize_email(email),
        )
        if access_key is not None:
            company.access_key = access_key

        company.save(using=self._db)

        return company

    def create_superuser(self, name, email, access_key):
        company = self.create_user(name, email, access_key)
        company.is_admin = True
        company.save()

        return company


class Company(AbstractBaseUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=False,
                            unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=False, null=False,
                             unique=True)
    access_key = EncryptedCharField(max_length=18)
    verification_key = EncryptedCharField(max_length=20, blank=True,
                                          null=True)
    is_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    callback_url = models.URLField(blank=False, null=True)
    objects = CompanyManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'name'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
```